# Create php variable from part of referring URL

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to work out a script to log IPs from poll votes on a message board, that will only be fired off if a vote is cast in one of our polls. Edit: I'm doing this via a web beacon, because I don't have access to the poll's programming. /edit

When the script fires off, it needs to know which poll is being voted in, since there are often multiple polls that are open at the same time, and log the IP of voters in a flat file that is dedicated to that poll.

First, I grab the referring URL, which is formatted like this:

http://subdomain.sample.com/t12345,action=vote

If 'vote' is found in the referring URL, the next thing I want to do is grab that t# and turn it into a variable, so I can log info in a file named t12345.txt or 12345.txt, either-or doesn't really matter, as long as it matches the topic number of the poll.

The numbers after the /t are the only thing that should change in this URL. There are currently 5 digits here, and I don't expect this to change any time soon.

**My question is:** How do I grab this t# from the URL and create a variable from it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: assign session id to each pole ... ?

Comment: I don't have access to the poll's programming, otherwise I'd rewrite the poll itself. I guess I didn't mention that, so I edited my post to add it.

Comment: why you have comma in your url ?

Comment: Because that's how it is, and there's no way for me to change that.

Comment: why no use & instead of comma ? why there is no way to change because i am unable to find any reason to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
preg_match('|/t[0-9]{5}|', $url, $matches);
if (count($matches)) {
    $t_number = $matches[0]; // "/t12345"
    $number = substr($t_number, 2, strlen($t_number)); // 12345
}
```

Assumptions:

1) The referring url will never have the pattern t#####. (t12345.com/vote)

2) You will always have five digits. (if this changes, you can do {5,6} to match 5-6 instances

Comment: I actually was thinking preg_match would be the way to go, but the syntax really boggles my mind. Thanks again!

Comment: Yup, no problem! For simple regex problems, I've found http://txt2re.com/ to be very useful. There's a ton of other sites as well, but that one is good at picking up common patterns.

Comment: Thanks for that link, Curtis. I've bookmarked it, and will check it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Curtis already answered, but here's a non-regex alternative:

1. Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the URL to get the "path".
2. Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a comma delimiter to get your t# as array element 0 in the result.
3. (optional) Use explode on element 1 of the result from 2 with a delimiter of = to get "action" in element 0 and "vote" in element 1 of this new result.

Eg.

```
$url = "http://subdomain.sample.com/t12345,action=vote";
$url_pieces = parse_url($url);
$path = str_replace("/","",$url_pieces["path"]);
$args = explode(',',$path);

t_number_thingy = $args[0];
```

Edit: added str_replace as parse_url will include slash on the path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Skrivener. I'm afraid I'm not good with arrays, either.

Answer (score 0):

Non regex solution (don't know about performance) and there is probably a better way but it works.

```
<?php

$var = "http://subdomain.sample.com/t12345,action=vote;";
$remove = "http://subdomain.sample.com/t";
$intCount = 5;

echo substr($var, strpos($var, $remove) + strlen($remove), $intCount);

?>
```

[phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gbc-nxr)

Comment: I just noticed your phpFiddle link. Thanks for that. I've bookmarked it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use regex on this you can also use [str_replace();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [basename();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

**Like:**

```
<?php
$ref = "http://subdomain.sample.com/t12345,action=vote";

if(substr($ref,-4)==="vote"){
    $ref = basename(str_replace(',action=vote','',$ref));
}

echo $ref; //t12345
?>
```

Or a one liner:

```
$ref = (substr($ref,-4)==="vote") ? basename(str_replace(',action=vote','',$ref)) : "Unknown";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Lawrence. It's interesting to see how many different ways there can be to accomplish the same thing. :)